# UITableViewController inside UITabBarController = unwanted padding on iOS 11

Tags: uitableview, uitabbarcontroller, padding, ios11

I need to have a UITabBarController hosting UITableViewControllers. My controllers are organised this way:

- UITabBArController

  - UINavigationController for tab 1

    - UITableViewController for tab 1
  - UINavigationController for tab 2

    - UITableViewController for tab 2
  - UINavigationController for tab 3

    - UITableViewController for tab 3

Screenshot of my storyboard:

[image]

It works well for iOS 8, 9 & 10. Here on iOS 9:

[image]

But on iOS 11, I have an extra padding at the top of my table views:

[image]

How to fix that? I've tried every single solution proposed on StackOverflow without success, it always work either on iOS 8, 9 & 10 or on iOS 11. I'm also nearly sure that it was working on all platforms this morning before I update Xcode from 9.1 to 9.2 :@ ...

Comment: Unrelated, but there is no need to embed the tab bar controller itself in a navigation controller if you don't plan to navigate away from it.

Comment: Well for the root nav controller, I wanted a nav bar. What is your Xcode version?

Comment: Could you try with a root nav controller as well? If I remove it problem is gone, but I need it on the real project.

Comment: You must have done something different, I just tried with a brand new project and got the problem. Did you exactly do: new project -> add nav controller -> add tabbar controller -> 2 * (add nav controller -> add tableview controller) ?

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a bug which occurs in projects that were created with Xcode 9.2. You should either:

- turn off translucency for the navigation bar of the table view
- override the header's height differently for different iOS versions:

  ```
  override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
      if #available(iOS 11, *) {
          return CGFloat.leastNormalMagnitude
      }
      return 0
  }
  ```

Comment: Overriding the headers height isn't working well as I'm using them and it changes their height as well (I could check to change the height only for the 1st one but I don't know what value to return for my normal headers). Turning the translucency off works but I want to keep it :/